# Parallel requests referring to the same stateful session bean

Tags: ejb, stateful-session-bean

I assume that an EJB container can process multiple interactions with the same client parallel. What does this mean for requests which use the same stateful session bean and influence their state? (this is more a theoretical question)

Do multiple requests really share the same instance of that bean? If not, in which else way does the container assure, that state changes caused by a request get propagated to and are accessible from a parallel request of that same client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While consulting [this site](http://what-when-how.com/enterprise-javabeans-3-1/the-singleton-session-bean-enterprise-javabeans-3-1/)  I realized that the EJB container is responsible für serializing multiple concurrent requests to stateful session beans.